# What is the best way to use .PAC in C# when request is redirected

Tags: c#, redirect, proxy, httpwebrequest, pac

**Background**

I have to use the proxy server specified by users in my application.
Right now, I check that the input proxy contains ".pac" or not. If yes, I'll get the real proxy from pac file. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12168/Using-PAC-files-proxy) Otherwise, I just set the input proxy to WebProxy.

```
public HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url, string proxy)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    if (proxy.ToLower().Contains(".pac")) 
    {
        string realProxy = GetProxyFromPac(url, proxy);
        request.Proxy = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(realProxy)) 
            ? new WebProxy() 
            : new WebProxy(realProxy, true);
    }
    else
    {
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
    }
    return request as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

And use the request like this.

```
var request = CreateRequest(url, proxy);
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

**Problem**

When the server redirects url to another url, I'll get request timeout.

Example:

- The input url **URL**
- The input proxy **PAC_P**
- GetProxyFromPac(**PAC_P**, **URL**) return **P**
- The redirected url **REAL_URL**
- GetProxyFromPac(**PAC_P**, **REAL_URL**) return **PP**

I found that it's because I set the proxy to **P** in the request and it will be used for all urls (including redirected urls) but **REAL_URL** is not accessible via **P**. 
I have to get **PP** from the **REAL_URL** and **PAC_P** and use **PP** to request to **REAL_URL**.

The first solution in my head is to get a new proxy every time the request is redirected and manually request to the redirected url.

```
var request = CreateRequest(url, proxy);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect ||
       response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved)
{
    request = CreateRequest(response.Headers["Location"], proxy);
    response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

**Question**

I think there should be an elegant way to handle this. It seems to be an extremely general case. **Do you have any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own IWebProxy class like this:

```
public class MyPacScriptProxy : IWebProxy
{
    protected string PacScriptUrl;

    public MyPacScriptProxy(string url)
    {
        PacScriptUrl = url;
    }

    public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }

    public Uri GetProxy(Uri dest)
    {
        // you can return your GetProxyFromPac(dest, PacScriptUrl); result here

        if (dest.Host.EndsWith(".net")) {
            return null; // bypass proxy for .net websites
        }

        return new Uri("http://localhost:8888");
    }

    public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.Proxy = new MyPacScriptProxy("http://localhost/proxy.pac");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have tried this. I found that GetProxy was not hit. I'll try it again tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Please ensure that IsBypassed() return false, otherwise GetProxy() will be ignored.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! Can't wait to try this.